# TFS - No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to set the default subscription

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am trying to run a task on TFS which requires AD set up. I managed to set up all connections, but for some reason Subscription on TFS is not selected.
I am not sure to what account do I have to log in, to set default subscription. -Default parameter is deprecated btw.

Task add-on I am trying to use is downloadable here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbengtsson.appservices-start-stop&showReviewDialog=true

TFS build error:
[image]

I tried to set up via power-shell:
[image]

Comment: How many Subscription do you have? Try to run Get-AzureSubscription to see which Subscription is Default. Do you use TFS on-premise or VSTS? I'd like to test this task on my side.

Comment: I have two subs, one is Visual Studio Enterprise and other Pay-as-go, but Visual Studio Enterprise is Default, I checked it says Default true. But I think this is only for power shell current session? I am not 100% familiar how does it work. I have to make it work on TFS though. TFS is not using on-premise to do builds, it uses Hosted machine by Microsoft. Task addon I am trying to make work is downloadable here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbengtsson.appservices-start-stop&showReviewDialog=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the **Azure AppServices Stop** task on my side, and found this task works perfectly with **Azure Classic** Connection Type, but while used **Azure Resource Manager** Connection Type, I got the same error message as you.

According to the [source code of **Azure AppServices Stop** task on GitHub](https://github.com/rbengtsson/appservices-start-stop/blob/master/Stop/Stop.ps1), this task actually uses Azure Power Shell below to stop the service:

```
$website = Get-AzureWebsite -Name $WebAppName
Stop-AzureWebsite -Name $WebAppName
```

It seems `Stop-AzureWebsite` only works with Azure Classic, as we can't find it in [Using Azure PowerShell with Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/).

In conclusion, if you want to use **Azure AppServices Stop** task, you need to choose **Azure Classic** Connection Type:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version of [AzureRM Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/switch-azurermwebappslot?view=azurermps-5.0.0) you now can use **Azure Resource Manager** connection type and use commands like:

Start-AzureRmWebApp
Stop-AzureRmWebApp

[image]